How to ensure correct drawing order in vispy
I need to mark certain features using rectangles and circles in an image. I have combined the Polygon and Image  examples from the vispy gallery to create the following code:
import numpy as np
from vispy import app
import sys
from vispy.scene import SceneCanvas
from vispy.scene.visuals import Ellipse, Rectangle, Image, Line
from vispy.color import Color
from vispy.io import imread

white = Color("#ecf0f1")
gray = Color("#121212")
red = Color("#e74c3c")
blue = Color("blue")
yellow = Color("yellow")

canvas = SceneCanvas(keys='interactive', title='Polygon Example', show=True)
view = canvas.central_widget.add_view()
view.bgcolor = gray
view.camera = 'panzoom'

# problematic line code1
line = Line(np.array([(-100, -150), (200, 250)]), connect='strip', method='gl', width=2, color=red, parent=view.scene)
rect = Rectangle(center=(-15, 20), width=150, height=100, color=yellow, border_color=red, border_width=2, radius=2, parent=view.scene)
ellipse = Ellipse(center=(-10, -10), radius=(150, 50), color=blue, border_width=2, border_color=red, num_segments=100, parent=view.scene)
# problematic line code2
# line = Line(np.array([(-100, -150), (200, 250)]), connect='strip', method='gl', width=2, color=red, parent=view.scene)

# Create the image
img_data = imread(r'read\some\image')
image = Image(img_data, cmap='gray', parent=view.scene)

# flip y-axis to have correct alignment
view.camera.flip = (0, 1, 0)
view.camera.set_range()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.flags.interactive != 1:
        app.run()


I have noticed an uncertainty in the order in which the visuals are drawn if the problematic line codes shown in the comments are swapped.
In the case where the line1 is uncommented and line2 is commented, the order of the visuals are
Image -> Ellipse -> Ellipse Border -> Rectangle -> Rectangle Border -> Line

In the other case, when the line2 is uncommented, and line1 is commented, the order becomes:
Rectangle -> Image -> Line -> Ellipse -> Ellipse Border -> Rectangle Border

It is strange to notice that the object (ellipse/rectangle) and its border behave like two different entities and are drawn independently. What is the correct way to get vispy to draw the objects in the same sequence in which they appear in the code (including the borders)? I am using vispy 0.14.3 and Python 3.10.
